# Hibernate Search failing while creating initial indexes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search

I'm trying to integrate Hibernate Search in a Spring Boot 2 app. I have tried different versions following the compatibility list on their site but I always get this error when the app is started and "fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();" is executed:

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HSEARCH000349: Some of the specified entity types ('class java.lang.Object') are not indexed, nor is any of their subclasses.**

After 3 days googling and trying lot of things I have no idea what else I can do.

---

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    ...
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>${opencsv.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.10.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

As the datasource configuration is handled by spring boot I don't have a persistence.xml file so I put the Hibernate Search properties in application.properties. Actually I put these properties also in hibernate.properties trying to make this work.

**application.properties**

```
...
spring.datasource.username=*******
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physicalstrategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
spring.jpa.hibernate.search.default.indexBase=/lucene/indexes
```

**hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
hibernate.search.default.indexBase=/lucene/indexes
```

**My entity Restaurant to be indexed:**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Indexed
@Spatial
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
public class Restaurant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
    private String name;
    private String address;
    @Latitude
    private Double latitude;
    @Longitude
    private Double longitude;
}
```

**I'm initializing Hibernate Search just after spring boot is started**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PlacesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
        SpringApplication.run(PlacesApplication.class, args);

        context.getBean(HibernateSearchService.class)
        .initializeHibernateSearch();
}
```

**And my Hibernate Search Service looks like:**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
@Slf4j
public class HibernateSearchService {

    private EntityManager entityManager;
    @Transactional
    public void initializeHibernateSearch() {

        try {
            FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I found the issue, very very silly issue....

My IDE just imported the wrong Indexed annotation
It set import org.springframework.stereotype.Indexed; instead of import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;

Comment: You saved me from hours and hours of searchs

Comment: same here...doh